# File Size Increasing But Text Not Being Written

Tags: java, append, stringbuilder, printwriter

I know SOMEONE has successfully done this. I simply want to write text to a Letterhead. It contains [Sample Letter head](http://www.freewebs.com/odelldesigns/apps/photos/photo?photoid=75212519)

```
    File myFile = new File("/tmp/letterhead.doc");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(myFile,true));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Why be a programmer im always stuck @ something dumb wasting my TIME ?? :( \n");

    pw.println(sb.toString());
    pw.close();
```

I have tried 
Apache POI - Failed

Java2Word - Failed

Is this a formatting problem, a encoding problem? I heard .rtf would be easier but people get nervous if they don't see .doc/.docx this needs to open in MSWORD because that what the Muggles live by.

I am willing to pay for something that isn't open source, if anyone knows. I don't want to look like a douche on Monday, plus i'm on 90 day probation GEE WHIZ!

Answer (score 0):

To generate a .doc/.docx from Java, you'll probably want to use one of those libraries you mentioned.  If they aren't working for you, an alternative would be to work with WordprocessingML directly.  WordprocessingML is basically XML that Word can understand, and render as a  Word document.

Below is an example of WordProcessingML.  If you save it to an .xml file, then open it in Word, you'll see that it's interpreted as a Word document.  You can then save this to a .doc/.docx from Word.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument 
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Hello JavaWorld.</w:t> 
    <w:br/>
<w:t>This is a great reporting tool.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

The example above came [from this site](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072828/build-ci-sdlc/new-options-for-java-reporting.html), which is definitely worth a visit.  At the bottom, there's some Java that can be used to create Excel spreadsheets.  You should be able to work off of that to write the code you need to create Word documents.

Comment: Dave I didn't come across this in my search so i'll have to look into it. At the high-level it seems to just create the documents for you, I can successfully write a .doc with the code that isn't the issue. The problem is writing it to the letter head which is also a .doc that contains a footer & header .

Comment: Since the letterhead is also a .doc, you can save it as a Word 2003 XML Document from Word.  Once you've done that, you should be able to work with the WordprocessingML to add whatever content you need.  I've tested out saving a .doc (with a header and footer) as a .xml in Word, making some changes to the .xml, then re-opening it in Word, and it looks like the header and footer are preserved.

Comment: Thanks I'll try later  :-) By the way I came across software named Aspose it does the job with Ease but comes  a HEFTY price tag